# Why I can't change the values in SQLite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I need to get user id from SQLite3 database and update it with new values. But I have some troubles with it.

```
db.each(`SELECT * FROM admins WHERE id = 1`, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    db.run(`REPLACE INTO admins (id, user_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES 
    (user.id, user.user_id, user.first_name, 
    "NEW LAST NAME");`)
})
```

`console.log(user)` returns:

```
{ id: 1,
user_id: 482078708,
first_name: 'ExampleFirstName',
last_name: 'ExampleLastName'}

events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: user.id
```

Why it shows this error? If I'm removing this code everything becomes okay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't know your `user` function parameter. Use command parameters

```
db.run(`REPLACE INTO admins (id, user_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);`,
       user.id, user.user_id, user.first_name, "NEW LAST NAME")
```

Note that now the references to `user` are outside of the SQL command string.

See: [Database#run(sql, [param, ...], [callback])](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementrunparam--callback) (if this is the API you are using).

Comment: I found the solution too: `db.run('REPLACE INTO admins (id, user_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES 
    (${user.id}, ${user.user_id}, "${user.first_name}", 
    "NEW LAST NAME");')`
But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that You need to put expressions inside `${}` when you're using backticks( ` )for a string. so instead of the string "user.id" You would have the value of the `id` field of the `user` object inside the string wrapped by backticks:

```
db.run(`REPLACE INTO admins (id, user_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES 
    (${user.id}, ${user.user_id}, ${user.first_name}, 
    "NEW LAST NAME");`)
```

But I don't know about sqlite so that may not solve the problem.